# Express multiple one-to-many and one-to-one relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am designing a delivery app. It has User, Address and Store models. I have following requirements:

1. User can have multiple delivery address
2. Store is located at only one location.
3. An address cannot be linked with both user and store.

Models looks as follow:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
    ...

class Store(models.Model):
    ...
```

First requirement can be shown as:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Second requirement can be shown as(in Address model as):

```
    store = models.OneToOneField(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also, second requirement can be shown as(in Store model as):

```
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is the best way to represent the third requirement. And how do I take care of serialization in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you center or problem on the Address model, you can handle this case during the [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects):

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    store = models.OneToOneField(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.user != None and self.store != None:
            raise ValidationError('Address must belong EITHER to user OR store, not both', code='invalid')
```

You may also want to handle the case if both fields are `None`. Note that both fields need to be allowed to be `null=True` on database level.

Comment: how would my serializer look like for User and Store?

I want to return something like,
user = {
  "first_name": "Jon",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "delivery_addresses": [
    {
      "address": ""
    }
  ]
}

store = {
  "store_name": "Store A",
  "location": {
    "address": ""
  }
}

[formatted json](https://jsfiddle.net/989kbf0h/1/)

Comment: Just use a [Django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/). You don't have to take care of anything yourself. Let Django do it :)